# How to change the GridView page Index

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

How to change Gridview pages based on the dropdown list selected index? the dropdown list is not inside the gridview, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi can you edit your question showing us the aspx markup and the databinding logic?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not working

Answer (score 2):

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">    
    </asp:DropDownList>

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    GridView1.DataSource = datatable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Important is than change of PageIndex is BEFORE DataBind.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the GridView's PageSize property to the value of your DropDownList's selected item value:

```
private void DropDownListPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.PageSize = DropDownListPageSize.SelectedValue;
}
```